# Help identifying 2 capacitors in a Synology DS415+

Tags: capacitor, identification, repair

I am hoping to get a little help in confirming the blue and red aluminium electrolytic capacitors in the attached image.  I think the red one is a 100uF 16V and the blue is a 560uF 6.3V but I just want to be sure, as I am not familiar with the other markings.  TIA

[image: photo of components on PCB]

Comment: Do you know that there is anything wrong with them? Are you trying to fix a problem, and if so - what prompted you to suspect capacitors?

Answer (score 2):

Probably 100uF/16V and 560uF/6.3V. The latter is probably low-Z.

56uF is also possible but I don't think it is so, from the relative size and other factors.

Answer (score 1):

The blue is maybe APSC6R3ELL561MH08S (Nippon Chemi-Con). The red is made by Nichicon.